# Backbone structure for custom objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Looking at some backbone examples, I see some simple models like this:

```
var Vehicle = Backbone.Model.extend(
{
   summary: function () {
   return 'Vehicles move';
   }

});
```

or

```
Vehicle = (function () {
return Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {

   },

   initialize: {

   }
});

})();
```

Edit: (clarification)
I was wondering if someone could explain the differences between the two ways of defining backbone objects and what's more conventional.  I know they don't have the same methods inside, but I'm more interested in how in the first one, they extend the backbone model, and the second one, they wrap it in a closure.  I'm not sure if I really grasp what's going on in each and when you would use which pattern.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first one has a summary method and the second one doesn't. Not sure if you're asking something else though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider the first form much more conventional, especially since I don't even see the second form on the main [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) website at all.

To understand how they do the same thing, first notice that Backbone.Model.extend() is a function that also returns a function:

```
> Backbone.Model.extend()
  function () { return parent.apply(this, arguments); }
```

So the variable `Vehicle` ends up being set to a function that is a model constructor method either way you look at it. I would consider the second form more indirect and unnecessarily complex, though: it is setting `Vehicle` to the result of calling a function that, itself, just returns `Backbone.Model.extend()`, so its just a more convoluted way of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If all the properties for the model are easy to define, pattern 1 is suggested. However, if any property is complex to implement thus need a "private" helper function which you do not want expose it either in your model or in global object, better to utilize the closure to hide it. that is the pattern 2.

An Example:

```
Vehicle = (function () {

function helper1() {} //don't want to expose it
function helper2() {}

return Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {

   },

   initialize: {

   }

   summary: function() {
      helper1();
      helper1();
   }

});

})();
```